# How to get the Latest DATETIME in my collection

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

My collection

```
"10/01/2016 4:00 PM"
"10/01/2016 11:00 AM"
"10/01/2016 12:00 PM"
```

I want to get : "10/01/2016 4:00 PM" since it is the current time and the latest at all. However when i use .Max() Function it returns the value of "10/01/2016 12:00 PM" which means it is just looking for the Highest Value of HOURS "12".

Comment: Thanks for editing. Im new here.

Comment: please post how you initialize your collection because if it is `DateTime`s it should work fine

Comment: No sir. When i sort descending  It sorts as from highest to lowest which is not what i want to. The sort i want should be like this: 
"10/01/2016 4:00 PM"
"10/01/2016 12:00 PM"
"10/01/2016 11:00 AM"

or using .Max() function i want to get the 4:00 PM

Comment: Seems like you sorting a `string` types, not a `DateTime`. Convert your collection first to the collection of `DateTime`. `var maxDate = stringCollection.Select(value => DateTime.Parse(value)).Max();`

Comment: @DarkKnight - Please show your code because when I try it's fine

Comment: I got it now thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comparing `string` values.

You need to convert your collection of strings to the collection of `DateTime`

```
var dateTimeCollection = stringCollection.Select(value => DateTime.Parse(value));
```

Then use `Max` method

```
var maxDate = dateTimeCollection.Max();
```

Comment: sry this is the correct one :). However is it correct too?
collection.Max(Value=>DateTime.Parse(Value.Date)); ?

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of Collection do you use? I had testet it with following Code

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>()
            {
                 DateTime.Parse("10/01/2016 4:00 PM") ,
                 DateTime.Parse("10/01/2016 11:00 AM"),
                 DateTime.Parse("10/01/2016 12:00 PM")
            };

            Console.WriteLine(list.Max());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

And it works

Comment: Yes your answer below is the correct one thanks @Fabio I'm not confused anymore :)